# removeClass() not working?

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I'm using some new CSS3 functionality to make a click function look like a flipping card. In doing so, the client has asked for the ability to flip back. I'm trying to use removeClass() to make that go, but I'm not able to. addClass() works fine, but the "flip" class is not getting removed. I'm using jquery 1.8.1.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flipper').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('flip');
    });
    $('#flipBack').click(function(){
        $(".flipper").addClass('flipBack').removeClass('flip');
    });
});
```

Comment: A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example of your problem would be useful

Comment: There's something else going on, your code should work, post a sample at http://jsfiddle.net so we can see all of your code. You can usually see the problem for yourself when you create a reduction

Comment: just to confirm, are you sure the `$('#flipBack').click(function()` is getting called? The syntax seems fine to me.

Comment: we can't help until you give us an example of your html.  Its most likely residing there.

Comment: It works fine when I test it: http://jsfiddle.net/kSg89/

Comment: @Guffa and fails in this case http://jsfiddle.net/kSg89/1/

Comment: And works again if you call `stopPropagation` http://jsfiddle.net/kSg89/2/

Comment: LOL @JuanMendes && Guffa

Comment: @SpYk3HH What's funny? I think your `&&` is pretty funny :)

Comment: @JuanMendes: Well... it looks like it fails, but it actually works, and then it works again immediately... :)

Comment: @Guffa They are all different code, with different behavior? I suppose solving a problem a step at a time is funny?

Comment: @JuanMendes: Why would that be funny?

Comment: @JuanMendes: Oh, you thought that I was talking about your two posts in a row. I wasn't. I was talking about the code.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the both events are called. And after removing the flip class in the second click it gets back in the first click

Comment: This makes sense if `#flipBack` is inside of `.flipper` http://jsfiddle.net/kSg89/1/

Comment: Since you didn't update your answer, I created an answer based on your idea,  my suggestion and @guffa's jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

Some html might help, perhaps a [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/), however, you could do with add remove alltogether.

If you set flipBack as default class (i'm assuming it may be animated but has a default state) then you can use jQuery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) much easier

```
$(function() {
    $('.flipper').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); $(this).toggleClass('flip flipBack') });
    // and if you really need it, tho i'm still unsure the full functionality here
    $('#flipBack').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); $('.flipper').toggleClass('flip flipBack') });
})
```

## jdFiddle Example

Are you sure both clicks aren't being called at same time? some html would realy help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that your `#flipBack` is inside of `.flipper`. You need to stop the event from bubbling if that's the case.

Here's a sample of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/kSg89/1/

Here's the solution http://jsfiddle.net/kSg89/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flipper').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('flip');
    });
    $('#flipBack').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".flipper").addClass('flipBack').removeClass('flip');
    });
});
```